# Faster and more efficient code than this? (Grabbing 9 unique random rows)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Note: I'm a PHP beginner which is why the code below might be bad.

Hi. I'm using this code at the moment to select 9 unique random rows and it works fine.

```
$quCountRows = $database->query("SELECT * FROM approved")->rowCount();
$arrRandomPictures = array();
while (count($arrRandomPictures) < 9) {
    $randNumber = mt_rand(1, $quCountRows);
    if (!in_array($randNumber, $arrRandomPictures)) {
        $arrRandomPictures[] = $randNumber;
    }
}
$quRandomPicture1 = $database->query("SELECT picName,picType FROM approved WHERE id='".$arrRandomPictures[0]."'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$quRandomPicture2 = $database->query("SELECT picName,picType FROM approved WHERE id='".$arrRandomPictures[1]."'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$quRandomPicture3 = $database->query("SELECT picName,picType FROM approved WHERE id='".$arrRandomPictures[2]."'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$quRandomPicture4 = $database->query("SELECT picName,picType FROM approved WHERE id='".$arrRandomPictures[3]."'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$quRandomPicture5 = $database->query("SELECT picName,picType FROM approved WHERE id='".$arrRandomPictures[4]."'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$quRandomPicture6 = $database->query("SELECT picName,picType FROM approved WHERE id='".$arrRandomPictures[5]."'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$quRandomPicture7 = $database->query("SELECT picName,picType FROM approved WHERE id='".$arrRandomPictures[6]."'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$quRandomPicture8 = $database->query("SELECT picName,picType FROM approved WHERE id='".$arrRandomPictures[7]."'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$quRandomPicture9 = $database->query("SELECT picName,picType FROM approved WHERE id='".$arrRandomPictures[8]."'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Although it may work I'm pretty sure the same results can be obtained with less queries. Which would hopefully result in the page loading quicker.

Any suggestions?

---

Here's the better code. Thanks to Amber!

```
$quCountRows = $database->query("SELECT * FROM approved")->rowCount();
$arrRandomPictures = array();
while (count($arrRandomPictures) < 9) {
    $randNumber = mt_rand(1, $quCountRows);
    if (!in_array($randNumber, $arrRandomPictures)) {
        $arrRandomPictures[] = $randNumber;
    }
}
$quRandomPicture = $database->query("SELECT picName,picType FROM approved WHERE id IN (".implode(', ', $arrRandomPictures).")")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Well, for a beginner you had a good hunch - if you see similar repetitive code, there must be a joined solution.

Comment: @GundarsMēness right on the nail. If you see yourself repeating code it's very, very likely there is a better way and it's good that you noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `in` instead of `==` and pass a list of IDs. That way you can get all of the results from one query rather than 9.

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example please? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: `SELECT foo, bar FROM table_name WHERE id IN (1,2,3)` will give you 3 rows in the result, the ones with id=1, id=2, and id=3.

Comment: Finally did it :) Took me a while but I finally got there! Thanks.

Comment: Also note that since you're already using PDO, you should really look into using prepared statements - they'll help you protect your web app from SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can order by a random number and get other results everytime.
This way, you only need one query!

```
SELECT picName, picType FROM approved ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0, 9;
```

Comment: Isn't `ORDER BY rand()` not to be recommended though? I thought it was the slowest way if you have a large table.

Comment: You're right... Up to about a 100, maybe 200 rows, this method is doable.

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` is terrible for performance because it computes a `RAND()` value for every single row in the table and sorts all of them (and can't use an index, because by definition it's random).